# scripting python install library with pip on virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'd like to use virtualenv in order to setup my environment and to install specific libraries.
I want to script the whole process, but so far, it's not working.

Here is my attempt:

```
import subprocess
import pip

virtualenv_dir="my_directory"

subprocess.call(["virtualenv", virtualenv_dir, "--system-site-packages"])

activate_this_file="{}/bin/activate_this.py".format(virtualenv_dir)

# instead of sourcing the /bin/activate file, I update dynamically
# my current python environment
execfile(activate_this_file, dict(__file__ = activate_this_file))
pip.main(["install","my_lib"])
```

This way, my_lib is installed on /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages instead of "my_directory/lib/python2.7/site-packages", as I wish.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with the following work-around:

```
# In main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess, os
virtualenv_dir="my_directory"

subprocess.call(["virtualenv", virtualenv_dir, "--system-site-packages"])
subprocess.call([os.path.join(virtualenv_dir, 'bin/python'),"-c","import pip; pip.main(['install','my_lib'])])
```

Comment: `virtualenv` and `pip` are python modules, so not sure why you needed to use `subprocess`.